# Как сделать таймер отсчета?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нажимается кнопка в игре, происходит действие и начинается отсчет (допустим 10 секунд), bool становится false. После прохождения таймера в 10с, значение bool изменяется на true. Можно снова активировать кнопку.

Comment: Почему все так любят ставить метку `unity3d-android` в каждый вопрос? Она ведь не имеет никакого отношения к подобного рода вопросам...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class TimedButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float cooldownTime = 1f;
    bool ready = true;

    void Update(){
        if(/*кнопка нажалась*/ && ready){           
            StartCoroutine(CooldownHandler())
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CooldownHandler()
    {
        ready = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldownTime);
        ready = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Перед тем как читать этот ответ, стоит написать что ответ RiotBr3aker хорош и оптимален для большинства ситуаций :)

---

## Альтернативный путь 1:

Если не требуется отображение времени, можно использовать DelayedCall при помощи внешних библиотек. Например в LeanTween:

```
//через 5 секунд вызвать код
LeanTweed.DeayedCall(5f, ()=>{ /*некий код*/});
```

Ассет:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/leantween-3595

И документация:

http://dentedpixel.com/LeanTweenDocumentation/classes/LeanTween.html#method_LeanTween.delayedCall

---

## Альтернативный путь 2:

Мой ответ -- это просто еще один вариант на тему. Использовать в юнити должно быть аналогично даному примеру. Так же в юнити можно написать и аналогичный класс который будет работать более точно на основе Update() и Time.DeltaTime.

Но чаще, все же, используется подход написанный RiotBr3aker т.к. это банально проще.

---

пример CountDownTimer-а на форме:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG0RU.gif

.

Использование:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer();//создаем инстанс
timer.SetTime(30,0); //выставляем на 30 минут
timer.StepMs = 33; //Выставляем шаг таймера (как часто вызывается TimeChanged)

//Подписываемся на событие TimeChanged и в нем обновляем значение лейбла
timer.TimeChanged += () => Label1.Text = timer.TimeLeftMsStr; 

// Подписываемся на событие окончания таймера и реагируем на него сообщухой
timer.CountDownFinished += () => MessageBox.Show("Timer finished the work!"); 

timer.Start(); //стартуем
```

И не забываем вызвать `Dispose();` когда таймер уже не нужен

---

Код таймера:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CountDownTimer : IDisposable
{
    public Stopwatch _stpWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public Action TimeChanged;
    public Action CountDownFinished;

    public bool IsRunnign => timer.Enabled;

    public int StepMs
    {
        get => timer.Interval;
        set => timer.Interval = value;
    }

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private TimeSpan _max = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000);

    public TimeSpan TimeLeft => (_max.TotalMilliseconds - _stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) > 0 ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_max.TotalMilliseconds - _stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) : TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
    
    private bool _mustStop => (_max.TotalMilliseconds - _stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) < 0;

    public string TimeLeftStr => TimeLeft.ToString(@"\mm\:ss");

    public string TimeLeftMsStr => TimeLeft.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff");

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeChanged?.Invoke();

        if (_mustStop)
        {
            CountDownFinished?.Invoke();
            _stpWatch.Stop();
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public CountDownTimer(int min, int sec)
    {
        SetTime(min, sec);
        Init();
    }

    public CountDownTimer(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        SetTime(ts);
        Init();
    }

    public CountDownTimer()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        StepMs = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
    }

    public void SetTime(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        _max = ts;
        TimeChanged?.Invoke();
    }

    public void SetTime(int min, int sec = 0) => SetTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(min * 60 + sec));

    public void Start() {
        timer.Start();
        _stpWatch.Start();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        _stpWatch.Stop();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Reset();
        Pause();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _stpWatch.Reset();
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        _stpWatch.Reset();
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose() => timer.Dispose();
}
```

Проапдейтил код т.к. до єтого он не точно работал.

Comment: Хорошее рассуждение на тему, радует, что на стэке чаще стали вспоминать про LeanTween :)

Comment: Очепятка LeanTweed.DeayedCall

Comment: Линтвин вообще офигенная вещь) Очень упрощает многие задачи

Comment: ready = false;
LeanTween.DelayedCall(5f, () => { ready = true; });  //// "Имя LeanTween не существует в текущем контексте." Как починить, а то я примерно представляю, но не знаю как, и верно ли я написал?

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов, нужен отдельный ассет - LeanTween

Comment: Ошибка CS0117 "LeanTween" не содержит определение для "DelayedCall".

Comment: не знаю, может ты библиотеку как-то криво подключил.  Этот метод находится внутри файла LeanTween.cs так что если он недоступен то не доступны должны быть и другие методы линтвина