# Как изменить секунды в таймере обратного отсчета

Tags: c#, таймер, countdowntimer

Есть класс взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/957760/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0?rq=1):

```
using System;

public class CountDownTimer : IDisposable
{
    public Action TimeChanged;
    public Action CountDownFinished;

    public bool IsRunnign => timer.Enabled;

    public int StepMs
    {
        get => timer.Interval;
        set => timer.Interval = value;
    }

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private DateTime _maxTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 30, 0);
    private DateTime _minTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    public DateTime TimeLeft { get; private set; }
    private long TimeLeftMs => TimeLeft.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

    public string TimeLeftStr => TimeLeft.ToString("mm:ss");

    public string TimeLeftMsStr => TimeLeft.ToString("mm:ss.fff");

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TimeLeftMs > timer.Interval)
        {
            TimeLeft = TimeLeft.AddMilliseconds(-timer.Interval);
            TimeChanged?.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            Stop();
            TimeLeft = _minTime;

            TimeChanged?.Invoke();
            CountDownFinished?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public CountDownTimer(int min, int sec)
    {
        SetTime(min, sec);
        Init();
    }

    public CountDownTimer(DateTime dt)
    {
        SetTime(dt);
        Init();
    }

    public CountDownTimer()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        TimeLeft = _maxTime;

        StepMs = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
    }

    public void SetTime(DateTime dt) {
        TimeLeft = _maxTime = dt;
        TimeChanged?.Invoke();
    }

    public void SetTime(int min, int sec=0) => SetTime(new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, min, sec));

    public void Start() => timer.Start();

    public void Pause() => timer.Stop();

    public void Stop()
    {
        Pause();
        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        TimeLeft = _maxTime;
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        Reset();
        Start();
    }

    public  void Dispose() => timer.Dispose();
}
```

Вызов:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer();//создаем инстанс
timer.SetTime(1,0); //выставляем на 1 минуту
timer.StepMs = 33; //Выставляем шаг таймера (как часто вызывается TimeChanged)

//Подписываемся на событие TimeChanged и в нем обновляем значение лейбла
timer.TimeChanged += () => Label1.Text = timer.TimeLeftMsStr; 

// Подписываемся на событие окончания таймера и реагируем на него сообщухой
timer.CountDownFinished += () => MessageBox.Show("Timer finished the work!"); 

timer.Start(); //стартуем
```

---

Как изменить секунды чтобы было не 999 а от 60 сек ?

Получается сейчас такой вид: 10:10.999 а нужно 10:10:60  - Одна минута 60 секунд.

И с помощью этого класса можно реализовать не обратный отсчёт а наоборот текущее время и дата сделать ( ну или к дополнению )  ?

---

[**Последнее изменение в коде**]

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer();//создаем инстанс
  timer.SetTime(1,0); //выставляем на 1 минуту
  //timer.StepMs = 33; //Выставляем шаг таймера (как часто вызывается 
  TimeChanged)

  //Подписываемся на событие TimeChanged и в нем обновляем значение лейбла
  timer.TimeChanged += () => Label1.Text = timer.TimeLeftStr; 

  // Подписываемся на событие окончания таймера и реагируем на него сообщухой
  timer.CountDownFinished += () => MessageBox.Show("Timer finished the work!"); 

  timer.Start(); //стартуем
}
```

В самом классе CountDownTimer изменил метод `TimeLeftStr`

```
public string TimeLeftStr => this.TimeLeft.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

После идёт отсчёт:  **12:00:59**

Но этот код не работает:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer();//создаем инстанс
timer.SetTime(1,0);
```

Не заменяет на нужное, всегда с 12 начинает.

Comment: 999 это не секунды, а милисекунды :) А что бы получить текущую дату - просто обновляй по таймеру нужный лейбл с `DateTime.Now.ToString()`

Comment: @Andrew, Точно) Хотелось бы без них, только (часы, минуты, секунды )

Comment: Измени "mm:ss.fff"(минуты:секунды.миллисекунды) на "hh:mm:ss" (часы:минуты:секунды)

Comment: @Andrew, Изменил, но теперь после того как я выставил `timer.SetTime(1,0);` в вызове таймер на одну минуту он показывает 12:00:59 Как это исправить?

Comment: `hh:mm:ss` => `"mm:ss"`

Comment: @tym32167, Изменил и там, сделал вызов на метод `TimeLeftStr` показывает перед началом то что нужно, но после всё ровно показывает 12:00:59 и идёт отсчёт от этого времени.

Comment: Откуда ж мне знать что и где вы изменили, вы же код после изменений не показали.

Comment: `"hh:mm:ss"` ==> `"mm:ss"`

Comment: @tym32167, А почему оно вмести с часами не работает, ну типо: 00:01:59 ? Если я ставлю "hh:mm:ss" - то у меня показывает от 12. `"mm:ss"` - отображает 01:59 как мне и нужно, но с часами какие-то проблемы, из-за чего это?

Comment: [`"hh:mm:ss"` => `"HH:mm:ss"`](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/19.2.php)

Comment: @tym32167, Так работает, последний вопрос, как тогда передать правильно параметры для  `timer.SetTime(1,0);` добавить часы, полагаю нужно добавить что-то в метод `SetTime` ?

Comment: Если вам надо передать часы, то вам надо добавить параметр для передачи часов, если вы об этом. Или я не понял вопрос. Также, вместо 3 параметров (часы, минуты, секунды, вы можете передавать [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен вот такой формат для даты [`HH:mm:ss`](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/19.2.php)