# Таймер в формах C#

Tags: c#, winforms, таймер

Делаю программку для тестирования, на первой форме пользователь выбирает уровень сложности (заключается сколько времени даётся для прохождения теста).
Код первой формы:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            form2.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Второй:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Shown += Form1_Shown;
        }

        private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (form1.radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                verticalProgressBar1.Value = 100;
                for (int i = 15 * 60; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    verticalProgressBar1.Value = i * 100 / (15 * 60);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }

            if (form1.radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                verticalProgressBar1.Value = 100;
                for (int i = 20 * 60; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    verticalProgressBar1.Value = i * 100 / (20 * 60);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
            this.Hide();
            form3.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Но после нажатия на кнопку в первой форме открывается сразу 3 форма (конец теста - итоговое окно). Как исправить? Если без if'ов и оставить один вариант, то тогда срабатывает. Как решить?

Comment: у вас какой то из `radioButton` отмечен при старте формы?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну я выбираю какой именно.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он бесполезен для сообщества. Код делает то что и должен по логике здравого смысла.

Comment: @Andrew любой код делает то что должен (внезапно). Как по мне, так невозможно написать код, который не будет делать то что должен. Странная причина для закрытия.

Comment: @aepot во-первых не любой. Бывают баги языка или фреймворка. Во-вторых он прямым текстом пишет что хочет открывать третью форму по таймеру, но. даже не делает попыток использовать таймер, а потом спрашивает почему код не работает, если он код для таймера пишет в Form1_Shown. Этот вопрос не несет никакой пользы сообществу.

Comment: Если кратко то вопрос можно переформулировать в "Почему не срабатывает таймер, если я использую вместо него метод Form1_Shown". Ответ "потому что этот метод не относится к таймеру никаким боком"

Answer (score 1):

Я как-то отвечал кодом таймера обратного отсчета (самый нижний блок по ссылке)

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957771/186752

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer();//создаем инстанс
timer.SetTime(0,30); //выставляем на 30 секунд
timer.StepMs = 33; //Выставляем шаг таймера (как часто вызывается TimeChanged)

//Подписываемся на событие TimeChanged и в нем обновляем значение лейбла на форме
timer.TimeChanged += { Label1.Text = timer.TimeLeftMsStr; }

// Подписываемся на событие окончания таймера и реагируем на него сообщухой (замени действие на нужное тебе)
timer.CountDownFinished += () => MessageBox.Show("Timer finished the work!"); 

timer.Start(); //стартуем
```